# Android : How to generate OTP for input field that takes email or phone number using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I have created signup page in Android that has input field which takes email or phone number
, after signup it should receive OTP for the respective input.I have done OTP verification for phone number.My question is my input field accepts either email or phone number. How do I make OTP verification in that case ?

this is the signup activity

```
package com.example.memorybus

import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.memorybus.databinding.ActivitySignUpBinding
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseTooManyRequestsException
import com.google.firebase.auth.*
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class SignUp : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySignUpBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivitySignUpBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        binding.textview.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Login::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        binding.btnSignup.setOnClickListener {
            val name = binding.name.text.toString()
            val email_ph = binding.emailPhone.text.toString()
            val relation = binding.relation.text.toString()
            val password = binding.passwordSignup.text.toString()

            if (email_ph.isNotEmpty())
            {
                val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(firebaseAuth)
                    .setPhoneNumber(email_ph)       // Phone number to verify
                    .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
                    .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
                    .setCallbacks(callbacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                    .build()
                PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter the fields",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }


            }


        }

    private fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    //Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success")
                    sendToLogin()


                    val user = task.result?.user
                } else {
                    // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                    if (task.exception is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                        // The verification code entered was invalid
                    }
                    // Update UI
                }
            }
    }

    private fun sendToLogin()
    {
        startActivity(Intent(this,Login::class.java))
    }

    private val callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
            // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
            // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
            //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
            // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
            //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without
            //     user action.
            //Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:$credential")
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
        }

        override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
            // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
            // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.
           // Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e)

            if (e is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                // Invalid request
                Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e)
            } else if (e is FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e)
            }

            // Show a message and update the UI
        }

        override fun onCodeSent(
            verificationId: String,
            token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken
        ) {
            // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
            // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
            // by combining the code with a verification ID.
           // Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:$verificationId")

            // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
            val intent = Intent(this@SignUp,OTP::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("OTP", verificationId)
            startActivity(intent)
           /* storedVerificationId = verificationId
            resendToken = token*/
        }
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Authentication support OTP based authentication for phone numbers only. The email equivalent would be to use [email link sign in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth).

Once user enters their credentials, check if it is a [valid email or phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505336/email-and-phone-number-validation-in-android) and call the relevant function.

If you want to use OTPs only then you'll have to build your own solution using Cloud Function similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68569999/13130697).